# создание barcode на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, barcode

Пробую создавать баркоды с помощью библиотеки  python-barcode
установил с помощью команды
`pip install python-barcode`

пробую запустить такой код

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

def testEan():
    EAN = barcode.get_barcode_class('ean13')
    ean = EAN(u'123456789011', writer=ImageWriter())
    fullname = ean.save('my_ean13_barcode')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testEan()
```

в итоге получаю ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "barcode.py", line 1, in <module>
    import barcode
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\barcode.py", line 2, in <module>
    from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'barcode.writer'; 'barcode' is not a package
```

Comment: Уточните версию Python и ОС.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов  python 3.7.4 win10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так.

```
pip uninstall barcode
pip install python-barcode
pip install pillow
```

https://pypi.org/project/barcode/ - нет никаких ImageWriter'ов

https://pypi.org/project/python-barcode/ - есть оные

Пользуйтесь виртуальными "средами"(окружением). https://python-scripts.com/virtualenv

Comment: на самом деле все было гораздо проще. Я назвал файл также как и библиотеку, после того как переименовал все заработало